# What is the inverse Laplace transform of $e^{as^2+bs}\frac{1}{1+cs}$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, laplace-transform

Suppose that the function $f$ is given by its two-sided Laplace transform:
$$
\int_{\mathbb R} f(x)e^{-sx} \, dx = e^{as^2+bs}\frac{1}{1+cs}
$$
where $a,b,c>0$ are positive real numbers. I want to find out what $f$ is but I'm struggeling to invert in the above Laplace transform.

Is there a simple way to find out what $f$ is?

Comment: The RHS is the product of the MGFs of a Gaussian and exponential distribution, so $f$ should be the convolution of their densities.

Comment: This question does not meet the MSE Guidelines. Context for this question? What have you tried? -1